# Operator Precedence Parser: Where do we keep reduced tokens?

Tags: compiler-construction

An Op Precedence Parser has a stack and an input buffer.

I believe that after popping, an "id" token is reduced to a variable "E".

For every pop of an "id" token from the stack after seeing a mathematical operator in the input, where is the popped token kept?

If the input is like id+id*id$ , by the time $ is reached, all the "id"s have already been popped. Where are they kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your goal is to build an AST, the `id`s (and other operand tokens such as literal constants) are put into the AST node created by the reduction.

If you're directly evaluating or generating three-address code or ..., then the answer will differ slightly. However, the broad outline is the same: operator-precedence parsing is a bottom-up parse algorithm in which the right-hand side of a production is *reduced* to the corresponding non-terminal (on the left-hand side of the production) when it's last input symbol has been read (and the lookahead indicates that the correct action is reduction).

Comment: So, this AST node is another data structure right? Array or linked list, something like that?

Comment: @Spandan Typically, it will be a `struct Node` containing an operator (`enum`) and two operands (`struct Node*`). But there are lots of variants. Of course, you also need to be able to make Nodes out of constants and ids, so it's a bit more complicated than that. See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree or craft your own google search.